# Mysql query on using SUM and Limit for calculating usage and cost

Tags: mysql, sum, limit

I have a mysql database called sensor_data. Every 30 minutes a script inserts the power usage to this database and also the cost depending on the day/night tariff

```
Rec   Date       Time              Reading   Usage  Cost    Tar
2771  2010-12-20 16:00:00 RFXPower 67044.6   0.5    0.09    0.18
```

What I am looking for is a mysql query that will return the last hour hour power usage and cost. Another query will return the daily usage and cost.
For the last query, it should simply sum the cost of the last two values in the cost column. I am trying todo this with the sum and limit, but I can't find how to limit the last 2 current records.

Comment: Is that sample line the literal inserted-into-database data? Hopefully not... Could you post your database schema along with an explanation of what all the numbers at the end represent? I'm guessing 67044.6 is the meter's current kWh reading, the rest is a total mystery.

Comment: is `Data` and `time` indexed?

Answer (score 0):

to get the last hour:

```
SELECT SUM(Cost)
FROM sensor_data
WHERE RecID > (SELECT Rec FROM sensor_data WHERE Date < CURDATE() OR Time < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR ORDER BY Rec DESC LIMIT 1);
```

and to get the daily total:

```
SELECT SUM(Cost)
FROM sensor_data
WHERE RecID > (SELECT Rec FROM sensor_data WHERE Date < CURDATE() ORDER BY Rec DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the SUM query only returns one aggregated row, you can't combine it with LIMIT directly. You could use a subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(cost) + SUM(tar) FROM (SELECT cost, tar FROM sensor_data ORDER BY rec DESC LIMIT 2) AS subquery;
```

Or you could use a date or time condition (`WHERE …`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I got you wrong, you only have problems with the third query; the first two queries are working well. For the third query (summing up the costs of the last two records), you could sort the result set in descending order and limit it to two records.